# use Graphics in paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, paintcomponent

I have the following code, b represent a ball class from another class. If I use b.draw(g,true); I don't see any result from the screen, however if I use g.fillOval(b.getX() - b.getRadius(), b.getY() - b.getRadius(), 2*b.getRadius(), 2*b.getRadius()); I got good result, I thought they both use Graphics and should work the same?

Thanks in advance!
Calum

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
  super.paintComponent(g); // Paint the background
  g.setColor(Color.RED);
  g.drawString("Hello, Action!", xPos-100, yPos-200);
  // Not working
  b.draw(g,true);
  // Working
  //g.fillOval(b.getX() - b.getRadius(), b.getY() - b.getRadius(), 2* b.getRadius(), 2*b.getRadius());
}
```

Full Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class Balloon
{
  private int xCenter, yCenter, radius;
  private Color color;

  /**
   * Constructs a balloon with the center at (0, 0),
   * radius 50, and blue color
   */
  public Balloon()
  {
    xCenter = 0;
    yCenter = 0;
    radius = 50;
    color = Color.BLUE;
  }

  /**
   * Constructs a balloon with a given center, radius and color
   * @param x x-coordinate of the center
   * @param y y-coordinate of the center
   * @param r radius of the balloon
   * @param c color of the balloon
   */
  public Balloon(int x, int y, int r, Color c)
  {
    xCenter = x;
    yCenter = y;
    radius = r;
    color = c;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the x-coordinate of the center.
   */
  public int getX()
  {
    return xCenter;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the y-coordinate of the center.
   */
  public int getY()
  {
    return yCenter;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the radius of this balloon.
   */
  public int getRadius()
  {
    return radius;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the color of this balloon.
   */
  public Color getColor()
  {
    return color;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the distance from a given point to the
   * center of this balloon.
   * @param x, y coordinates of the point
   */
  public double distance(int x, int y)
  {
    double dx = x - xCenter;
    double dy = y - yCenter;
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
  }

  /**
   * Moves the center of this balloon to (x, y)
   * @param x x-coordinate of the new center
   * @param y y-coordinate of the new center
   */
  public void move(int x, int y)
  {
    xCenter = x;
    yCenter = y;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the radius of this balloon to r
   * @param r new radius
   */
  public void setRadius(int r)
  {
    radius = r;
  }

  /**
   * Returns true if a given point is strictly inside this balloon;
   * otherwise returns false
   * @param x, y coordinates of the point
   */
  public boolean isInside(int x, int y)
  {
    return distance(x, y) < 0.9 * radius;
  }

  /**
   * Returns true if a given point is on the border of this balloon;
   * otherwise returns false
   * @param x, y coordinates of the point
   */
  public boolean isOnBorder(int x, int y)
  {
    double d = distance(x, y);
    return d >= 0.9 * radius && d <= 1.1 * radius;
  }

  /**
   * Draws a solid circle if makeItFilled is true and
   * outline only if makeItFilled is false
   * @param g graphics context
   * @param makeItFilled draws a solid circle if true
   */
  public void draw(Graphics g, boolean makeItFilled)
  {
    g.setColor(color);
    if (makeItFilled)
      g.fillOval(xCenter - radius,
                 yCenter - radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
    else
      g.drawOval(xCenter - radius,
                 yCenter - radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
  }
}
```

Testing Program:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class FlyBalloon extends JPanel
                 implements ActionListener
{
  private int xPos, yPos;  // hold the coordinates of the message
  private Balloon b;

  public FlyBalloon(Balloon b)
  {
      this.b = b;
  }

  // Called automatically after a repaint request
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g); // Paint the background
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawString("Hello, Action!", xPos-100, yPos-200);
    // Not working
    b.draw(g,true);
    // Working
    //g.fillOval(b.getX() - b.getRadius(), b.getY() - b.getRadius(), 2*b.getRadius(), 2*b.getRadius());
  }

  // Called automatically when the timer "fires"
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    // Adjust the horizontal position of the message:
    yPos--;  // subtract 1
    if (yPos < -100)
      yPos = getHeight();
    this.b.move(xPos,yPos);

    repaint();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Action Demo");

    // Set this window's location and size:
    // upper-left corner at 300, 300; width 400, height 600
    window.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 600);
    Balloon b = new Balloon(150,150,100,Color.RED);


    //  Create panel, a FlyBalloon object, which is a kind of JPanel:
    FlyBalloon panel = new FlyBalloon(b);
    panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);  // the default color is light gray

    // Add panel to window:
    Container c = window.getContentPane();
    c.add(panel);

    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);

    // Set the initial position of the message:
    panel.xPos = panel.getWidth() / 2;
    panel.yPos = panel.getHeight() ;

    // Create a Timer object that fires every 30 milliseconds;
    // attach it to panel so that panel "listens to" and
    // processes the timer events; start the timer:
    Timer clock = new Timer(30, panel);
    clock.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what your `b.draw(...)` method does. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: How does `ball` actually work? As camickr has already suggested, a runnable example which clearly demonstrates your problem will provide you with a much greater chance of getting an answer that helps you solve your problem

Comment: Posted full code for both programs.

Comment: *"Posted full code"* Tip: Add @camickr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. Only one person can be notified per one comment.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use b.draw(g,true); I don't see any result from the screen,
>
> however if I use g.fillOval(...)  I got good result,

In both cases I see the text and the balloon move up on the screen, so it seems to work for me.

However, if it doesn't work for you then you need to do some debugging to see what the difference is.

When I look at the code I see:

```
  g.fillOval(xCenter - radius, yCenter - radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
```

and

```
g.fillOval(b.getX() - b.getRadius(), b.getY() - b.getRadius(), 2*b.getRadius(), 2*b.getRadius());
```

So instead of doing all your calculations in the method call write your code like:

```
int x = xCenter - radius;
int y = yCenter - radius;
int size = 2 * radius;
System.out.println(x + " : " + y " + " : " + size);
g.fillOval(x, y, size, size);
```

This allows you to display the values used to paint the oval.

Do the same for the other method.

Then you can compare the output from both approaches to see what the difference is.